# What should I put in the Rails model definition for the index I just added to a MS SQL Server 2008R2 column?

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-server-2008, model

I have a table `orders` on an MS SQL 2008R2 server
`orders` has a primary key of `id`
`orders` has a column called `ordering_date` that is type `datetime`
I created an index of column `ordering_date` called `ordering_date_ndx` on the server using a snippet of SQL.  I did try to use a migration, but running the migration timed-out on this table of 23 million records.

2 Questions:

1. What, if anything, should I put in app/models/order.rb to make use
   of the index.
2. Will code like this make use of the presence of the index and optimize the SQL query?

> ```
> list=Orders.find(ordering_date.year == 2006)
> ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik Rails doesn't care about indexes on databases. There is no query optimization on the basis of indexes in Rails. If you do sorting or filtering on a column (especially on big tables) it's helpful to add indexes. This helps your database server to do these operations more effective.

However the better approach to add an index is to let Rails do it via migrations than doing it manually. It could be if a SQL snipped as well. This ensures that the index is in place on all environments and servers.

Why this takes to long in Rails I have no idea. But you can run SQL in a migration:

```
def up
  execute "ALTER TABLE orders ADD UNIQUE ordering_date_ndx (ordering_date)"
end
```

I don't know about MS SQL syntax but I guess it can be adapted.

Comment: Thanks iltempo.  I started off trying a migration that looks just like yours.  The table has 23 million records and is 12GB.  Ran for 10 or 11 minutes and then reported a timeout error.  I then tried some sql on the server directly and it ran for 10 or 11 minutes and worked.  Now that I've done it, I realize I don't know how to make good use of that date ordered index via either rails or sql, which is too bad.  I suppose I will try making a few sql query strings that do what I need and issue them via rails and its find_by_sql method.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer.

Using:

```
SELECT     ordering_date
FROM         my_table
WHERE     (ordering_date > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2008-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND ordering_date < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2008-02-01 00:00:00', 102))
```

Gets me a very speedy result.

Prior to adding the index, this query would take 3 minutes to execute.  With the index, it takes 2 seconds, which changes how we can use this information for sure.

I 'discovered' that MS SQL Server 2008R2 has a *Display estimated execution plan* feature that confirms use of a primary key and the index.

I suppose I will next make a ruby method that wraps this sql and uses the find_by_sql method.